# SQL query to return only one lowest price per location from result set

Tags: sql

for this example, results of rate calculations are stored in a temp table `@results`
This table contains

```
code    | loc    | total     
661098  | 105    |  96.49 
661098  | 106    |  70.03 
661098  | 107    |  81.53 
702998  | 105    | 104.54 
702998  | 106    |  70.03
```

using the following query, we can get the lowest price per location

```
  select cr.loc, cr.total as lowest_total, cr.code 
  from @results cr
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT loc, MIN(total) as lowest_total
        from @results
        GROUP BY loc) inside 
  ON inside.loc = cr.loc
  and inside.lowest_total = cr.total
```

which gives us the following

```
 loc     |   total   | code
 105     |   96.49   | 661098
 106     |   70.03   | 702998  <---
 106     |   70.03   | 661098  <---
 107     |   81.53   | 661098
```

Note the two results for `loc=106`... we want to randomly select (or better the latter/higher `code` value) of the two so there is just one `total` returned per `loc`

Is there a more efficient (SQL-wise) way of accomplishing this other than doing yes another nested select or join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number()` instead:

```
select r.loc, r.total, r.code
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by loc order by total desc, code desc) as seqnum
      from @results r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: slick... sent to DBA for evaluation

Comment: feedback is it worked brilliantly.  Will digest in detail later for my own edification.  Thanks.